# how to filter records by attribute in xml Fields - EF Codefirst

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

In my Application, I used EF Codefirst, one field in my table is XmlField structure Like below:

```
<Attributes>
  <Attribute ProductAttributeId="80" ProductAttributeValueId="200" />
  <Attribute ProductAttributeId="70" ProductAttributeValueId="400" />
</Attributes>
```

my data in Database like below:

[image]

I want just get all rows where `productId=10` and `ProductAttributeId="80"`.

```
var result = context.ProductAttributeCombinations
                    .Where(row => row.ProductId == 10)
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .Where(row => row.ProductAttributesXML.Any(rowx => rowx.ProductAttributeId == 80 ))
                    .ToList();
```

I'm getting SQL profiler, this query just used `ProductId` in where clause and select all rows with `productId` , performance of this query is low (I think)

ProductAttributeXML Like belowe :

```
[NotMapped]
    public List<ProductAttributeXML> ProductAttributesXML
    {
        get
        {
            return XElement.Parse(ProductAttributeXML).Elements("Attribute".Select(row => new ProductAttributeXML 
                   { 
                      ProductAttributeId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Attribute("ProductAttributeId".Value), 
                      ProductAttributeValueId = Convert.ToInt32(row.Attribute("ProductAttributeValueId".Value)  
                   }).ToList();
        }
        set { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, EF will ignore any conditions on `ProductAttributesXML` field because it marked with `[NotMapped]` attribute. Instead you should change type from `List<ProductAttributeXML>` to `string` and remove `[NotMapped]` attribute, then you can create filter like this: `ProductAttributesXML.Contains("ProductAttributeId=\"80\"")`. And sure, you must convert `XML`(`List<ProductAttributeXML>`) to `string` type before writing it to DB and reverse - from `string` to `XML`(`List<ProductAttributeXML>`), after you have retrived data back.